# How can I get second shortpath?

Tags: neo4j

I created big graph database. Graph includes relationships between organizations. I would like get shortpath between two nodes.
I filtered relationships types by next query

```
MATCH (o:Organization) WHERE Id(o) =  23806112
MATCH (o1:Organization) WHERE Id(o1) = 24385058
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((o)-[*1..10]-(o1)) WHERE 
ALL (r IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) WHERE 
(type(r) = 'OrganizationFounderOrganization' AND r.DateFrom <= datetime('2019-03-13') ) 
 OR (type(r) = 'OrganizationFounderPerson' AND r.DateFrom <= datetime('2019-03-13') ) 
 OR (type(r) = 'OrganizationChief' AND r.DateFrom <= datetime('2019-03-13') ) 
 OR (type(r) = 'OrganizationManagingCompany' AND r.DateFrom <= datetime('2019-03-13') ) 
 OR (type(r) = 'OrganizationPhone') 
 OR (type(r) = 'OrganizationAddress' AND NOT EXISTS(r.DateTo) ) 
)
RETURN p SKIP 0 LIMIT 30
```

Filters by relationships do not may be combined because they could use other filters.
My execution plan by this query

http://joxi.ru/E2pNPDDH9Rpger

[image: Execution plan 1]

When I get paths, I filter nodes by other conditions (capital, status) and if I get not right paths I  apply next query with filter by bad nodes.

```
MATCH (o:Organization) WHERE Id(o) =  23806112
MATCH (o1:Organization) WHERE Id(o1) = 24385058
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((o)-[*1..10]-(o1)) WHERE 
ALL (r IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) WHERE 
(type(r) = 'OrganizationFounderOrganization' AND r.DateFrom <= datetime('2019-03-13') ) 
 OR (type(r) = 'OrganizationFounderPerson' AND r.DateFrom <= datetime('2019-03-13') ) 
 OR (type(r) = 'OrganizationChief' AND r.DateFrom <= datetime('2019-03-13') ) 
 OR (type(r) = 'OrganizationManagingCompany' AND r.DateFrom <= datetime('2019-03-13') ) 
 OR (type(r) = 'OrganizationPhone') 
 OR (type(r) = 'OrganizationAddress' AND NOT EXISTS(r.DateTo) ) 
)
AND ALL (n IN NODES(p) WHERE NOT Id(n) IN [15665,1557884,7888953]
RETURN p SKIP 0 LIMIT 30
```

Execution plan second query

http://joxi.ru/KAxWPDDcMJGyY2

[image: Execution plan 2]

In the process of executing second query neo4j become unresponsive and I should restart container

**Neo4j version** 3.4.7

**Store Sizes**

Count Store 5.69 KiB

Label Store 16.02 KiB

Index Store 9.27 GiB

Schema Store    8.01 KiB

Array Store 8.01 KiB

Logical Log 16.53 MiB

Node Store  1.18 GiB

Property Store  20.33 GiB

Relationship Store  8.79 GiB

String Store    18.73 GiB

Total Store Size    58.56 GiB

**ID Allocation**

Node ID 84686407

Property ID 532508736

Relationship ID 276570526

Relationship Type ID    13

**Container memory limit** 122880mb

**Processor** 32 core